# How to program game with sequence of events

Tags: c++, updates, updating, sequential, game-theory

I am coding for the NDS in c++. I am planning on writing a game in which events happen sequentially and change depending on the player's choice, like a decision tree. Example:

===Locations===

- Hallway: 2 doors the player can go through
- Bathroom: Has secret entrance to basement
- Basement: Leads back to the hallway
- Bedroom: Leads to Bathroom

===Sequence===

[image]

In each room, key presses would be constantly checked for. So this is the basic and generally bad way to code a sequence that I originally thought of:

```
void drawText()
{
    //writes the specified text to the screen depending on the room
}
void playGame()
{  //This function gets called to play through the whole game
    drawText();
    while(1)
    {
        updateKeys();
        if (newPress()) //New key is pressed
        {
            if (getButtonInt()==BATHROOM_INT)
                bathroom(); //it will launch the basement function as a subroutine
            else //Bedroom
                bedroom(); //it will launch the bathroom function as a subroutine
            drawText();
        }
        //When returning from room function, the 
    }
}
```

Some of the many disadvantages of this method are:

- Near impossible to implement multiplayer since everything would need to be constantly updated
- Nearly impossible for other features to get updated (such as a frame/time Tracker)
- Adding an option to go between rooms would cause recursion and possibly a memory overflow

So, the question: **What is the best alternative that would fix these disadvantages?**

Yes, I could write everything within a switch statement and have a variable outside the playGame function track the location in the switch statement, but the structure does not seem readable or logical.

Comment: You probably want a data structure that, for each room, defines which rooms you get to with a certain direction of movement.

Comment: Research "state" design pattern or state machine.  Your diagram looks like the drawing of a state machine with transitions.

Comment: Research "relational database tutorial" and "database normal forms".  This could help you later on.

Comment: As a complement of Thomas Mathews answer, give a look at: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm, smells like a state machine.  Your states are called locations.  The doors are transitions to other states.

There are many methods to implement state machines:  `switch` & `case`, `if` ladder, or lookup tables (or `map`s).

For developing the first one or two states, I use `switch` or `if` statements.  However, after the 2nd state, I usually convert to a lookup table.

A lookup table allows you to add more states without changing the state logic or what I call the lookup engine.

The lookup table would look something like:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+  
|Present | state for    | state for    | ... |  
| state  | transition 1 | transition 2 | ... |  
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

One implementation is a constant array of structures.  Search for the Present State ID, then pull out the next state value depending on the transition ID.  Simple.

For more fun, you can substitute pointers or references to functions for the "state for transition" boxes (fields).  This allows you execute functions depending on a transition.

Expanding this, you could have a container of state tables, for example one state table for each "game level".

Try changing your perspective from execution oriented to data driven.  You may be able to make most of your game table driven and have a small "engine".   Hmmm, looks like this could be expanded to using story boards and ...

**Edit 1: Maps & Databases**
If you choose to use something like an `std::map`, you'll need to split the lookup table into `{key, value}` pairs.  One key looks like the present state.  The value looks like the transition boxes.  But wait, ...

The transitions are looking like a container of relationships or associations.  A transition ID *is associated* with a state ID or state function.  Smell's like another table or map.

All this data is often referred to as a *database*.  You could use a `database` to contain your states.  Wow, it would handle the storage and data types for you.

But, I digress.  One step at a time...

Comment: Definitely a state machine. Don't forget 'action for transition to state 1' etc.